# C# Inherited Events With Custom Arguments

Tags: c#, events, interface

Im trying to specify an event in an interface with custom arguments. I need the event argument to be an object. I've tried to strip the following code down as much as possible. Im currently getting the following error.

```
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: obj
LittleObject.IObject.add_ChangeEvent (System.EventHandler`1 value) 
(at LittleObject.cs line : [where the comment is])
```

Code

```
public class ChangeEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public ChangeEventArgs(SomeClass c){ someClass = c;}
    public SomeClass someClass;
}


public interface IObject {
    void OnChangeEvent(ChangeEventArgs e);
    event EventHandler<ChangeEventArgs> ChangeEvent;
}


public class LittleObject : IObject{    

    public event EventHandler<ChangeEventArgs> ChangeEvent;

    public fireEvent(){
        OnChangeEvent(new ChangeEventArgs(new SomeClass()));
    }

    event EventHandler<ChangeEventArgs> IObject.ChangeEvent{
        add{                                // error here
            lock (ChangeEvent) {
                ChangeEvent += value;
             }
        }
        remove{
            lock (ChangeEvent){
                ChangeEvent -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnChangeEvent(ChangeEventArgs e){
        if(ChangeEvent != null) {
            ChangeEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
}


public class Main {

    IObject currentObject;

    void init(){
        currentObject = new IObject();
        currentObject.ChangeEvent += new EventHandler<ChangeEventArgs>(OnChangeEvent);
    }

    void doStuff(){
        currentObject.fireEvent();
    }

    public void OnChangeEvent(object sender, ChangeEventArgs e) {
        SomeClass someClass = e.someClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code compiling? You are trying to instantiate an interface `new IObject(); `

Comment: plus: lock is expensive - do you really need it? There is simple technique to avoid lock through assigning of ChangeEvent into local variable inside of fireEvent method.

Answer (score 7):

This code is quite messy, but I believe the reason you are getting the exception is because you are locking on a `null`-reference.

When you do:

```
add
{
    lock (ChangeEvent) { ... }
}
```

The compiler is actually using the private *field* backing the `ChangeEvent` event (see [field-like event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664455%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). Note that the initial value of this field is `null` (it has not explicitly been assigned an initial value, say through a field-initializer).

Now the first time someone subscribes to the "wrapping" event (`someObject.ChangeEvent += ...`), your *custom* `add` accessor is called, resulting in an attempt to take a lock on the *object* referred to by that field (the lock actually needs some data  in the object-header called a 'sync-block'). Of course, there is no such object, which is what makes the lock go bang.

As for the strange `obj` parameter, that's the one from [`Monitor.TryEnter(object obj, ref bool lockTaken)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679.aspx), which is what a C# lock statement compiles down to (previous versions of C# targeted a different method).

Honestly though, I would strongly consider redesigning this entire piece of code.

EDIT: Clarified the use of the wrapping event.